# codeigniter MVC inserting sensitive data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using `codeigniter` to build a page where users can `like` the post of another user.

I have three pages in this example, `view_page.php` , `model_page.php` and `controller_page.php`.

My `view_page.php` looks like this

```
<?php foreach($members as $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value['post_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value['post_title']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="like/<?php echo $value['post_id']; ?>">Like</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`Controller_page.php`

```
function like($post_id) {
    $this->load->model('model_page');
    $this->model_page->like_user($post_id);
    redirect('controller_page/viewdata');
}
```

**My question is,**
If a user with `user_id = 1`, posts something on the `view_page.php` (as shown in the image below), his `post_id`, `post_title`, and like button will show.

If another user with `User_id = 22`, likes that post, how do I add `user_id=22` in the `mysql` table, to know which user liked the post?

I was thinking of passing the `user_id=22` in the `url` of the like button, but then people can just manipulate the likes but changing `user_id` in the address bar.

How do I do it correctly?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can make a table where you store all likes
For Example.

```
id post_id user_id
1  1       22 
2  1       44
```

Comment: I know, but how do I pass the users who like the post into the table? Thanks

Comment: I want to do that exactly, but not sure how

Comment: You can use Session variable in php. The user which is login, just get id for that user and and post id from url. 
For Example User A with id (2) like post with id(1) so you will get user id from session ($_SESSION) which will be 2 and 1 post id an then save in database.

Comment: in Codeigniter you can also use session library like $this->session->userdata("user_id")

Comment: Thanks but my question is, if I pass user id in the url, people can change the user id that is being passed through the url and manipulate likes. How do I prevent that from happening?

Comment: @mark use encryption library of CI https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: if you does not  want use encryption use ajax submission.

Comment: you can base64 encode to pass in ur land then use base64 decode to get back original value.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

The Whole code for your questions would ask many aspects , As of now the solution provided by Tanseer UL Hassan is the best DB design ,now since your question is how to implement it , you can code in the following manner:

1) Create the variable which is to be passed to the controller :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidUserIdFromSession" id="hidUserIdFromSession" value="<?php echo $someUserIdFromSession;?>">
```

2) Use ajax to Insert data in the above-mentioned table, like this :

```
$('#yourButton').click(function() {
//Modify this according to your button name
var postId = "Get your post id here";
var userId = $("#hidUserIdFromSession").val();
     $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '<?php echo base_url("your/url/comes/here")?>',
     data: "postId="+postId+"&userId="+userId,
     success:function(response){
         //Your succes functions code comes here(Alert or any other processing).
     }
  });
});
```

3) Get the values inside controller function like this:

```
public function functionName(){
  //This is the same function which is called inside ajax call
  $arrReturn = array();
  $postId = $this->input->post('postId');
  $userId = $this->input->post('userId');
  $inserted = $this->model->insertLikeData($postId,$userId);
  //this is a call to model function in which you will actually make the Query to insert the data.
  if($inserted){
   $arrReturn['status'] = "Success";
   $arrReturn['data'] = array();//In case if you want to send some data.
  }else{
   $arrReturn['status'] = "Error";
   $arrReturn['data'] = array();//In case if you want to send some data.
  }
  $arrReturn = json_encode($arrReturn);
  echo $arrReturn;
}
```